# close a form without using invoker method?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Hi i have a main form which has several MDI forms . I have a user Authentication to check  if users are given rights to a certain MDI Form . This all happens on form Load , so if the user does not have rights the from will immediately close. However i wanted to ask wether there is another method other then the invoker method.

```
 Me.hide
 Me.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Me.Close))
```

Comment: Why don't you check if they have permission before they even open it?

Comment: Closing a form has always been `Me.Close` why would you need `MethodInvoker`?

Comment: BeginInvoke is only required if you're working with threads! If you are trying to close the form other than main thread you may require it. I agree with @ObieMD5 to check the permission before opening the form as it may help you save a little amount of memory.

Comment: @DonA i tried me.close but since its an MDI it was throwing an Error that the form was not showing or something like that , So using an Invoker is a good option.

Comment: @jparthj  Sorry if i havent been detailed. See i am not the project Manager and My manager is always busy with client side issues so i rarely meet him to propose about something. The project i am doing is a VB6 migration project. So as long as the code from VB6 still works in Vb.net use it. So the checking of permissions in the VB6 project was in form load so i followed the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your interface is MDI, I would assume that you're using a menu or a button, at least something with a click event, to open the form.  Put the Authenmtication in the click event handler before you open the form, and if the authentication fails notify the user of that instead of opening the form.  Not only is this a more efficient use of resources, it would also be more secure since a system lag could leave the information on the form visible before it is closed.

Comment: Yes.  Furthermore, don't even let the user click the button or menu item.  Set its Enabled property to False so it is crystal-clear that the feature is not available.  Also completely removes the need to scatter the authentication checking code all over the place.  Clean and usable UI begets clean code.

Comment: So its more of how the users uses the software rather than using code. I see i guess i can use a boolean check method Thanks for the info